# Hadoop 2.2 chain MapReduce jobs Map -> Reducer -> Map -> Reducer

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, chaining

I have two MapReduce jobs, the output of the first Reducer is the input of the second Mapper :

```
Map1 -> Reduce1 -> Map2 -> Reduce2
```

For now `Map2` reads from the files outputted by `Reduce1`. So `Map1 -> Reduce1` and `Map2 -> Reduce2` are independant.

It works, but it would be easier and I think more optimized if the output of Reduce1 was directly the input of Map2.

Is there a way to do that ? In this case `Map2` would be just an identity mapper so it would be even better if I could do :

```
Map1 -> Reduce1 -> Reduce2
```

Reduce1, Map2 and Reduce2 have the same input and output types.

Thanks !

Comment: You can still use an identity mapper as Mapper2, by using:
`conf.setOutputFormat(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);` for the first Driver class and `conf.setInputFormat(SequenceFileInputFormat.class);` for the second driver class. I don't know the syntactic changes for chaining jobs in hadoop 2.2,so I will not post an answer (yet).

Comment: good idea of using SequenceFileOutputFormat as suggested by #vefthym , which gives optimization

Comment: @vefthym Nice, that's way better like that. But I still have to use a temporary file, there is no way to directly pass the data from `Reduce1` to `Map2` ?

Comment: I don't think there is. Maybe I'm wrong though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my understanding these points i can tell you (may or may not help you, correct me if i am wrong):

1) map 1-> reduce 1-> directly to mapper2 : for optimizations are addressed in spark cluster computing framework (using in-memory computations, avoiding unnecessary read/writes to hdfs).

2) if you want something like reducer1 ->reducer2 . you have to think how you can write the logic in one reducer itself , but the problem here is its all depends on your requirement i mean the aggregation on which keys you want to perform (in more detail : reducer1 receives same set of key, on which only u can act the task of next aggregation).

3) In Hadoop the protocol is like this only :  map --> then aggregation , if any next aggregation , it has to come from a Userdefinedmapper/IdentityMapper.

hope this helps :)

Comment: 1) If I don't have to, I rather use only Hadoop and MapReduce.

2) The types of the keys are the same but not their values.

3) If I have to use an IdendityMapper it's not a problem, I just don't want to use temporary files between `Reduce1` and `Map2`.